# Possible to associate an azure subnet in one resource group to a virtual network in another resource group?

Tags: powershell, azure

In Azure, is it possible to associate an subnet in one resource group to a virtual network in a different resource group?  I can't get my powershell scripts to do it, and my guess is that it's not possible, but thought I'd check around for an official answer.

Thanks,
Casie

Comment: Could you draw us a diagram of what you are trying to achieve? I would like to understand exactly what you need, so I can give you the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/) explains what you can move and what you cannot move in Azure resource group without detail or limitations for majority of items..

When you move items with powershell, you have to supply `ResourceId` of the item you want to move. If you try `Get-AzureRMResource` and `Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork`, you will see the `Virtual Network` item is associated with `ResourceId` but `subnets` are just a sub configuration with a Etag. Combine with the article above, my take is, you might be able to move entire `Virtual Network`, but not a subnet.

Still, I consider moving network related resource in azure extremely risky.